# Palindrome Checker need a hand

Tags: javascript

I'm working on freeCodeCamp's [Palindrome Checker.](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/palindrome-checker) My code is a bit messy but it pretty works on every test except the nineth one. `palindrome("almostomla")` should return `false` but in my code it returns `true`instead. I think my nineth code has a little problem but couldn't solve that. I wonder where am I missing something.

```
function palindrome(str) {
    let str1 = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d:]/gi, '');
    let str2 = str1.replace(/,/gi, '');
    let str3 = str2.replace(/\./gi, '');
    let str4 = str3.replace(/_/, "-");
    let myStr = str4.toLowerCase(); //My string is ready for play

        for (let i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
            if (myStr[i] != myStr[myStr.length - (i+1)]) { //I think there is a little mistake on this line
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only checking the first and last characters of the string. You should `return true` only after all iterations have finished:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  let str1 = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d:]/gi, '');
  let str2 = str1.replace(/,/gi, '');
  let str3 = str2.replace(/\./gi, '');
  let str4 = str3.replace(/_/, "-");
  let myStr = str4.toLowerCase(); //My string is ready for play

  for (let i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
    if (myStr[i] != myStr[myStr.length - (i + 1)]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("foof"));
console.log(palindrome("fobof"));
console.log(palindrome("fobbf"));
```

Note that your initial regular expression is sufficient - it removes all characters that aren't alphabetical, numeric, or `:`, so the other 3 regular expressions you run later are superfluous. Since you're using the `i` flag, you can also remove the `A-Z` from the regex:

```
const stringToTest = str.replace(/[^a-z\d:]/gi, '');
```

It would also probably be easier just to `.reverse()` the string:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  const strToTest = str.replace(/[^a-z\d:]/gi, '');
  return strToTest.split('').reverse().join('') === strToTest;
}
console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("foof"));
console.log(palindrome("fobof"));
console.log(palindrome("fobbf"));
```

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks for advices and your time. I couldn't learn to solve problems without iterate them. I always find myself writing "for let i =0 bla bla" and I only realize shorter answers after I check the solutions. I am taking notes also but couldn't imagine them on next problems 